# How to over-ride React-Table default sort for date formats like 'MM-DD-YYYY' (07-22-2021)?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-table

```
const columns = [
            {
                Header: 'Last Login',
                accessor: 'lastLogin',
                disableFilters: true,
                Cell: row => <div style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>{row.value}</div>,
            }
]
```

For the default sort, it considers only the date

ex :

let dates = ["07-12-2020","11-05-2020","09-14-2021"]

after default sort = ["07-12-2020","09-14-2021","11-05-2020"]

Its should be = ["11-05-2020","07-12-2020","09-14-2021"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use :

```
sortType: (a, b) => {
  return new Date(b.values.lastLogin) - new Date(a.values.lastLogin);
}
```

Then its like

```
const columns = [
            {
                Header: 'Last Login',
                accessor: 'lastLogin',
                disableFilters: true,
                sortType: (a, b) => {
                  return new Date(b.values.lastLogin) - new Date(a.values.lastLogin);
                }
                Cell: row => <div style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>{row.value}</div>,
            }
]
```